# Is there an inverse function of SVGGeometryElement.getPointAtLength?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have the coordinates of a point somewhere along an SVGPath. I need to be able to find the distance along the path to this point, eg calling getPointAtLength(distance) would return my point.

This needs to run in Javascript in a browser.

Does anyone know how to do this efficiently or if there is an existing library that does this?

I think I've managed to work out an algorithm involving

- Splitting the path into segments
- Using the bounding box of each segment to work out on which segment the point lies
- Splitting the segment into two halves to generate two paths
- Checking the bounding boxes of the two paths to work out on which path the point lies.
- Repeat the last two steps until I'm sufficiently close to my point.

I haven't thought of a better way of doing it than this but I'm hoping someone has already solved this to avoid me re-inventing the wheel.

If it helps my point is calculated using svg-intersections to calculate the intersection of two paths. In effect, my I need to be able to animate from my point to the end of the path.

Comment: Wouldn't it help to split the path at that point into two and run the animation only for one half?

Comment: @ccprog That's an interesting idea that might work. I've actually got lots of intersections on paths that I need to do this for so I'd end up with a lot of small paths but that might not be a problem. (It's actually for a machine embroidery design program I'm playing with so the animation is the path the stitches will take)

Comment: That distance might not be unique if you had a path that ran from A to B then back to A, The distance to A is either 0 or 2 x (B - A).

Comment: It looks like https://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/ will do the job using either the intersection or the project functions.